# Error: Main method not found in class Purchase

Tags: java

Create a Java program that uses the Purchase class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Purchase
{
String ItemName;
double ItemPrice;
int ItemQuantity;
double ItemTotal;

public void setItemName(String newItemName)
{
    ItemName = newItemName;
}

public void TotalCost(double newItemPrice, int newItemQuantity)
{
    ItemPrice = newItemPrice;
    ItemQuantity = newItemQuantity;
}

public void readInput ()
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

try
{
    System.out.print("Enter Item Name : ");
    ItemName = br.readLine();
}

catch (IOException e)
{
}
    System.out.print ("Enter Item Price & Item Quantity.");
    System.out.print ("For Example 95.50 Price 8 Quantity is entered as");
    System.out.print ("95.50 8");
    System.out.println ("Enter price of item & Quantity of Item, now:");
    ItemPrice = sc.nextDouble();
    ItemQuantity = sc.nextInt();
}

public void writeOutput ()
{
    System.out.print(ItemName + " " +ItemPrice + " " +ItemQuantity + " Total Cost " +ItemTotal);
}

    public String getItemName()
    {
        return ItemName;
    }
    public double getItemPrice()
    {
        return ItemPrice;
    }
    public int getItemQuantity()
    {
        return ItemQuantity;
    }
    public double TotalCost()
    {
        double ItemTotal = ItemPrice * ItemQuantity;
        return ItemTotal;
    }
    }
```

Where And How can i put the static void main (String []args) ???
help please thanks
when i run this program.. process completed but i got still Error: Main method not found in class Purchase please define the main method as:public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: Your code has no main-method. Add something like `public static void main(String[] args) {...}` to your code.

Comment: Just add it. You already have the necessary signature in your question: `public static void main(String[] args)`. You'd then probably call `readInput` and `writeOutput` somehow, just how I'll leave for you as an excercise (I guess that's what you're required to figure out yourself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the main method anywhere in your class between the other methods. For example:

```
public class Purchase
{
  String ItemName;
  double ItemPrice;
  int ItemQuantity;
  double ItemTotal;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Purchase purch = new Purchase();
    //further actions here
  }
...
}
```

Comment: `public static void main (String []args)
 {
 Purchase purch = new Purchase();
  
 System.out.println(purch.readInput() +purch.writeOutput);
 }
}` 

error :'( cannot find symbol

Comment: It's ``purch.writeOutput()``  You missed a parenthesis there.

Comment: Also, those two methods are of return type "void" which means, they won't give any values back. Hence you cannot print those. You just call them. But the writeOutput method prints something by itself. I guess you need to work on your basic Java skills a bit more - no offense.